# How to solve the memory leak in Berkeley DB batch insert mode?

Tags: c#, berkeley-db

I'm using Berkeley DB v5.3.21 to insert a massive amount of data (100K records) to a BDB queue.

When I started using the batch insert mode, aka, using `MultipleDatabaseEntry`, it seem to cause a memory leak in the un-managed memory section.

- How can I resolve that issue?
- Has anyone ever stumbled upon such issue with BDB?

P.S

As an alternative solution, I thought to just use .Net `FileStream` in order to write my data to a file, since the implantation will include:

- One sequancial writer.
- Multiple random access readers.
- Fixed data entry size.

Do you think it should be simple enough to implement?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend posting you question to the Oracle Berkeley DB forums.
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=271